# How do I move items up/down in text file

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

How do I move items/values up and down a text file. At the moment my program reads a text file, an uses a while to make sure it stop when there is no more lines to read. I used an if statement to check if counter equals the line of the value I want to move. I am stuck not sure how to continue from here.

```
  _upORDown = 1; 

    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("textfile.txt"))
    {
        string line = reader.ReadLine();
        int Counter = 1;
        while (line != null)
        {

            if (Counter == _upORDown)
            {
              //Remove item/replace position

            }
            Counter++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: you can read the file replace values and then write it back overwriting the old version.

Comment: What should you do when Counter == _upORDown ?  Are you supposed to be writing out the file?

Comment: You can do `while(!reader.EndOfStream)` instead of `while(line != null)`
Also you should to `line = reader.ReadLine()` inside your loop or you'll just be stuck in an infinite loop.

Answer (score 3):

You can read the file in memory, move the line to where you need it, and write the file back. You can use `ReadAllLines` and `WriteAllLines`.

This code moves the string at position `i` up by one line:

```
if (i == 0) return; // Cannot move up line 0
string path = "c:\\temp\\myfile.txt";
// get the lines
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(path);
if (lines.Length <= i) return; // You need at least i lines
// Move the line i up by one
string tmp = lines[i];
lines[i] = lines[i-1];
lines[i-1] = tmp;
// Write the file back
File.WriteAllLines(path, lines);
```

Comment: @user1285872 `i` is an integer variable set to the zero-based line number that you want to move up by one.

Comment: okey thank, keeping getting an error "Error 1 'System.Array' does not contain a definition for 'length' and no extension method 'length' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Array' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
"

if (lines.length <= line) return;

Comment: @user1285872 Oops, you're right, it should be `Length`, not `length`.

Comment: Thanks, got another error, "Error 1 Operator '<=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'string'"

Comment: @user1285872 `i` is supposed to be an `int`.

Answer (score 0):

@dasblinkenlight's answer, using LINQ:

```
string path = "c:\\temp\\myfile.txt";
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(path);
File.WriteAllLines(
    path,
    lines.Take(i).Concat(
        lines.Skip(i+1)
    )
);
```

This deletes the line at position `i` (zero-based) and moves the other lines up.

Adding to a new line:

```
string path = "c:\\temp\\myfile.txt";
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(path);
var newline = "New line here";
File.WriteAllLines(
    path,
    lines.Take(i).Concat(
        new [] {newline}
    ).Concat(
        lines.Skip(i+1)
    )
);
```